# What is the probability to complete 3 patterns on the balls?

Tags: probability

We take out from the basket with unique x balls -  y balls, and need a probability of the patterns complete (all three together). For that i need a conditional probability that third pattern complete, if we already have first two. All patterns consider it's own balls amount, and numbers

For example: we take 50 balls from the basket of 100

we check pattern: 1, 3, 5 ball in first 30 of them.
3, 4, 7 balls in all 50,
1,3,4,8 balls in 40

What is the probability, to have all three pattern together?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: @Xoque55 i'll add it to the question now

Comment: This question makes no sense at all to me.  And I really tried to read it.  You haven't set up your conditions in well phrased English sentences.  What basket?  Is the "pool" in the basket?  Why do we have to take out 20 balls before we can check the first 10?  What does "necessary balls" mean?  What does "wasted balls" mean?  Why are we checking if ball 3 is in 50 balls after checking if ball 3 is in 30 balls?  What does "in 40" mean?  (In a randomly chosen set of 40 out of 50 or in some well-defined set of 40?)  It seems like it might be an interesting question but it's baffling as written.

Comment: @Wildcard pool/basket is the same. We take out 20 balls, and need a probability of the patterns complete (all three together). For that i need a conditional probability that third pattern complete, if we already have first two. All patterns consider it's own balls amount, and numbers

Comment: @Wildcard thank you so much for you notice, i realized how bad is description. I put the origin task in the question.

Comment: @Mira, thanks for the edit.  I would try to edit to improve the English but I'm afraid I still can't parse this well enough to be sure I've got it.  By "pattern" do you mean "a ball with a specific number"?  Or do you mean "a sequence of specific numbered balls being drawn out consecutively in a specified order, such as drawing ball #1 followed by ball #3 followed by ball #5"?  In which case I don't understand how you can have the pattern 1-3-5 AND the pattern 3-4-7, since balls 4 and 5 cannot *both* immediately follow ball 3.  Or does "pattern" refer to *non*-consecutive sequence of balls?

Comment: @Wildcard, so we take random 7 balls from busket and got 1,2,3,4,7,8,9 Pattern 1 is: that in first 5 (of this 7) we have a balls 1,3  (yes, we have) pattern 2: in first 7 we have 1,2,4,7( yes, we have. ) And pattern 3 that we have 1,3,4 in first 6 balls. Yes we have. So all three patterns are complete.

Answer (score 1):

All three events are independent otherwise you shall not have events A1, A2 and A3 occur like what you have said.  In other words, if A1 were to mean the first 10 and you have 2 necessary, then you cannot have the event A2 meaning the first 20 and only have 1 necessary and further you can't have A3 meaning the first 15 and have suddenly 5 necessary unless the definition of necessary means different things every time and that is what you are getting at.  Then it becomes almost next to impossible to find the intersection of these events to calculate the conditional probability.  I could be wrong but this is what my sense is.

If they are all independent then the conditional probability is $P(A_3/A_2A_1) = P(A_3)$  and that $P(A_3)$ is a hypergeometric probability calculated alike like the one for A1 which is $\frac{{m_1 \choose2}{m_2 \choose 1}{(N-m_1-m_2)\choose (n_1-3)}}{{N \choose n_1}}$

and for A3 it is $\frac{{m_1 \choose5}{(N-m_1-m_2)\choose (n_3-5)}}{{N \choose n_3}}$

where $m_1$ in N are necessary, $m_2$ in N are wasted and $N-m_1-m_2$ in N are unknowns.

Is this the problem of your making.  Could you let us know the source of the problem?

Comment: The source of a problem is a real task for the computer game with the random outcome. The whole task is very big, and i have resolved it, for the case when balls amount in checks in increasing (each An is checked on more balls then An-1). And the last step is to make it universal :)

Comment: We can have only 1 necessary in 20, even if we have 2 necessary in 10. Couse in first 20 we check  only "is there balls number 1, 3, 4? " And in 20 we check  "is there balls number 1, 4, 5? " So finally we need in the last check 2, 4, 5.  4 and 5 included in the second check and only 4 included in the first. You can assume it as some pattern search

Comment: How did you understand the question?  Are you familiar with similar questions already?  Perhaps you could edit the question to make sense for those of us who aren't.  :)  The line "is there 3, 4, 7 balls in all 50?" is particularly baffling to me.

Comment: @Wildcard assume it as a pattern, we check do we have a pattern 3, 4, 7 in 50 balls. We have pattern A1 in x balls and pattern A2 in x+10 balls, do we have pattern A3 in x+5 balls?

Comment: Patterns has common balls (overlay each other)